# SF newbie: Need to offer a bounty but have no rep

Tags: discussion, bounties, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

So I recently earned the Tumbleweed badge on SF for [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/136328/netbios-name-service-requests) question.  What's a SF newbie to do to get an answer??

All my accounts are linked but I didn't get the 100 you usually get so I don't have enough for a bounty.  I also know my limits and me actively participating on SF is probably a bad thing for that community.

(I'm hoping this MSO advertisement helps a little...)

Comment: Disassociate your SF account and then reassociate using an account that now has enough rep (your meta one for example). This should give you the bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, this is by design.  The usual alternative to offering a bounty is adding new information to the post.  That will bump it to the main page, where it'll get more eyeballs.  You may have heard that bumping is discouraged, but on these sites that's only true if you don't add new information about research you've done or techniques you've tried since your initial post/last update.

+1 for knowing your limits, by the way.  I'm useless on SF as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48675/bounty-questions-should-get-bumped-periodically/48700#48700), there are many ways to get better answers for your questions. Bounties are not the only way, in fact, bounties do not always work.

If people are not answering your question, you should engage anyone who *did* and then attempt to edit your question based on their feedback to be easier to answer.

Then, after you think you have gathered enough extra information (or clarifications) you should edit the question, and it will be bumped to the top of the active page. This means that not only will more people see it, it will also be a *better question* than it was before.

Make sure to respond to the commenters and answers with the "@" syntax so that they are informed that you have responded.

**EDIT**

The Bounty feature was intended as a reward for people who have invested the time to gain the reputation. So it is definitely [by-design] that users with low reputation can not offer a bounty. But there are still ways to get the answers you are looking for without a Bounty