# Reopening a discussion for a question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

As I was typing a question I discovered (Thanks to SOF suggestions) that there is similar question: [Does webcam recording with Flex strictly requires a media server (FMS, Red5, Wowza,etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989598/does-webcam-recording-with-flex-strictly-requires-a-media-server-fms-red5-wowz)

However I noticed that it's fairly old and some of the links proposed in the answers don't really work anymore!

What is the best way to reopen the discussion for that question:
1- Show I submit similar question?
2- Show I put comments on answers (I did already for can't guarantee I will get responses back)
3- Other ideas?

Comment: So [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046) is the canonical discussion of this topic if you 1) own the questions or 2) have edit power on it. If those conditions don't apply there is [How to bring attention to an old question you didn't ask to bring it up to date? ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60334). Finally, note that the power to put bounties on *other* peoples questions has been added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bring attention to an old question you didn't ask to bring it up to date?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60334/how-to-bring-attention-to-an-old-question-you-didnt-ask-to-bring-it-up-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still open. Answer the question with good / current info, and it will get bumped to the front page.