# Feature comparison is subjective? Argumentative? Impossible to answer?

Tags: support

I asked for [feature comparison and performance tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4954076/399268). Both are **very very very objective** things... or so did I think.

Or argumentative? How? "Feature X is present." "No, it's not!" "Yes it is!"

It's closed now. Where was a I wrong in asking such a question?

**Closing reason:** It's ***impossible*** to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument.

Impossible? Really?

Comment: Same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639043/entity-framework-4-vs-nhibernate. I could have really benefited from an up-to-date answer to that question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely there will be subjective *answers* to this question, these should be addressed separately. The question was in my opinion very objective. That is, I completely agree with you, and voted for reopen. I hope others will too.

Answer (score 0):

It was wrongly closed as Subjective & Argumentative. It should have been closed as a duplicate, for example of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913547/mysql-vs-sql-server-vs-oracle)

Comment: @Pekka: Hi! Have seen you around. That said, that is a question from Dec 16 '09. More than a year old? New versions? And more than that, no performance test has been asked for.

Comment: But that question does not address performance. This one does.

Comment: @aiiobe @101 Re performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707765/database-performance-benchmark

Comment: @101 I see your point about the question's age, but common practice is to try and revive the old question, e.g. using a bounty. It may be justified to ask "what's the status this year" questions on *very* rapidly evolving technologies, but the database market doesn't change that quickly. Much, if not most of what was true in 2009 is still true today

Comment: @Pekka, agreed.

Comment: @Pekka: Are you sure reviving the old question with a bounty would only result in new answers? I'm to trust that *after* being closed on this question as subjective? I've been running into false subjectives quite often here that it feels - to me - the system doesn't work. (See a few of my other meta support questions for examples.)

Comment: @101 yeah, how to deal with existing old questions is an ongoing discussion. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60334/how-to-bring-attention-to-an-old-question-you-didnt-ask-to-bring-it-up-to-date However, I have had great success reviving old questions using bounties. I don't see why this wouldn't work in this case. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294355/php-yaml-parsers