# Why is the question not bumped by a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, bump

I've just added a bounty to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735158/image-is-not-clickable-inside-anchor-only-in-ie7), but the question was not bumped to [interesting questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/)! Tried for cca 10 minutes and nothing. Why?

Reading these references, it should be:

- [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48681/166308

Note that I've added tag "html" to my favourite tags so that it's displayed but it doesn't help. The same thing happened to me recently with some other bounty I placed...

Comment: Maybe it isn't on your interesting questions list? Because it was definitely bumped, I can see that by just looking at the last activity date.

Comment: @lunboks it hsould be, I have one of the tags ("html") in my favourite tags. I've added it for this purpose.

Comment: When the last activity was [22 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5735158/revisions), I didn't see it either, [not even in incognito mode](http://i.stack.imgur.com/74mI0.png), @lunboks. (Meanwhile, another edit was made.)

Comment: Exactly Arjan, thank you for genial proof! :-)

Comment: (You almost ruined the test with that edit `;-)`)

Comment: :-)) @Arjan, but even my retag hasn't bumped it. Strange!

Comment: I think I did see your retag bump it, @Tomas. Also, I see it on the homepage right now, after the additional edits. However: not in incognito mode. (I did not see your 22 minute version on the logged-in non-incognito page either, but nothing in my ignored tags should have hidden it, and right now it's even highlighted given my interesting tags.)